# How to disable ssl verification for text_request() of api.ai / dialogflow

Tags: ssl, python-requests, dialogflow-es

The python client of api.ai/dialogflow provides a method for sending queries and get responses through text_request(). Here's the code block

```
def main():

    ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    request = ai.text_request()

    request.lang = 'de'  # optional, default value equal 'en'

    request.session_id = "<SESSION ID, UNIQUE FOR EACH USER>"
    request.query = "Hello"
    response = request.getresponse()
    print (response.read())
```

But the thing is `text_request()` uses *HTTPSConnection class* for sending requests which is incompatible with my master server page's *HTTPS* connection.  As, I have to use websocket and I am invoking api.ai request within my main `server.py` which is served by *uWSGI* server served with self signed ssl certificate for the *HTTPS* connection.

So, calling `text_request()` in *HTTPS* connection with self signed ssl giving me following error,

> file "server.py", line 84, in chat_message
>       response = request.getresponse()   File "/home/user/uwsgi_Test/virtual_frame/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apiai/requests/request.py",
>   line 128, in getresponse
>       self._connect()   File "/home/user/uwsgi_Test/virtual_frame/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apiai/requests/request.py",
>   line 82, in _connect
>       self._connection.connect()

Here's the `getresponse()` method from [`request.py`](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client/blob/master/apiai/requests/request.py)

```
def getresponse(self):
        """Send all data and wait for response.
        """

        if getattr(self._connection, 'sock', None) is None:
            self._connect()

        end = self._prepage_end_request_data()

        if end is not None:
            self.send(end.encode('utf-8'))

        self._beforegetresponce()

        return self._connection.getresponse()
```

Whereas it's working fine for HTTP requests.

So, in that case, I think there's two ways out to resoleve:

1) `text_request()` will not check for the security certificate at all. Something like in the python requests `verify = False` -

> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)

2) Sending the self signed certificates as a parameter to text_request(). So, while sending requests and getting response security certificate could be verified with the certificate file I would be sending.

How could I actually extend the `send_text()` method as above. Or, is there any  support of disable ssl verification from api.ai python client itself?

Comment: Dialogflow only provides APIs via HTTPS[0] are you asking how you can send a request to the same domain via HTTP and have the API call work?
[0]https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query

Comment: No, I have to use HTTPS with to ssl verification. I created an issue with more details https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client/issues/60    Please check that out